# IdentityServer3 using LinkedIn as external login

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver3

Trying to use LinkedIn as an external login but I keep having this error. After authorization screen. It goes to `/callback` instead of the initial application.

> There is an error determining which application you are signing into.
>   Return to the application and try again.

Here's my configuration

```
private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,    
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = "[...]",
        ClientSecret = "[...]"
    });
}
```

I'm not really sure how to configure the client either. I know we need the flow.Authorization code. But beyond that I'm lost.

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "[...]",
    ClientName = "Linkedin Client",
    Enabled = true,
    Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCode,
    RedirectUris =
        new List<string> {_baseUrl, "http://localhost/mtthelloworld"},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris =
        new List<string> {_baseUrl},
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
    {
        new Secret("[???]".Sha256())
    },
}
```

*Edit added ConfigureIdentityServerConfig:*

```
private void ConfigureIdentityServer(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var idsFactory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
        .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
        .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());
    idsFactory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(typeof(UserService));

    var idsOptions = new IdentityServerOptions()
    {
        SiteName = "SSO",
        SigningCertificate = VcCert.Load("CN=cert.local"),
        Factory = idsFactory,
        RequireSsl = false,
        LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions()
        {
            EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
            EnableHttpLogging = true,
            EnableKatanaLogging = true,
            WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true
        },
        PluginConfiguration = ConfigureWsFederation,
        AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
        }
    };

    appBuilder.Map("/identity", idApp => { idApp.UseIdentityServer(idsOptions); });

    appBuilder.UseIdentityServer(idsOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to obtain client id and client secret from LinkedIn. This is usually done by registering your application on the external provider side - LinkedIn.
Note that, when you are delegating authentication to external provider, then your server is a client and LinkedIn is a server.

Regarding the configuration method for external providers, do not call `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` inside this method. Instead configure only the LinkedIn authentication middleware.

```
private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationType = "LinkedIn",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
        ClientId = "[...]", // client id you've obtained from LinkedIn
        ClientSecret = "[...]",  // client secret you've obtained from LinkedIn
    });
}
```

You don't need to create new `Client` as you're doing it in your second code snippet. These classes are for meant for clients of your application, and as I've said earlier in this case your application is the client.

**EDIT**

You do not need to configure `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` in the server where you host `IdentityServer3` - let's call this server  *an identity provider*.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
    {
        // ...
        AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
        {
            IdentityProviders = (IAppBuilder builder, string signInAsType) =>
            {
                builder.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = "LinkedIn",
                    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                    ClientId = "[...]",
                    ClientSecret = "[...]"
                };
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

The question that you could ask is - well, then where do I need to use it? The answer is simple - use it in clients that are delegating authorization to your *identity provider*.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I deleted the two lines of codes and now I'm getting this configuration error `A default value for SignInAsAuthenticationType was not found in IAppBuilder Properties. This can happen if your authentication middleware are added in the wrong order, or if one is missing.`

Comment: You're right! I just noticed I was missing `SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,` It works now!